# How can an If statement return True if another function doesn't return an error?

Tags: python, try-catch

I'm setting up a script and I need to create an if statement where the if statement is True if another function doesn't return an error.

For the moment, I've tried this:

```py
def function1():
   try:
     doSomething()
     return A (not a bool here)
   except:
     return 'Error'
     raise
```

```py
if function1() != 'Error':
   print(True)
```

I search a way to avoid the `return 'Error'` in my `function1`.

Literally, I'm trying to obtain:

```py
if 'there is no error' in function1():
   print(True)
```

Comment: Wrap your call to `function1` in it's own `try/except`.

Comment: Don't have `try` and `except` in `function1`, and instead have it in the caller.

Comment: Your function can only return a value, or raise an exception. Exceptions are clear signals for errors. Return values *may* indicate an error, depending on what meaning you ascribe to them. Here your "an error occurred" return value is `'Error'`. Traditionally you may rather use `False` or `None`, but there's no fundamental difference. If you don't like ascribing that meaning to specific values, just don't catch the exception inside `function1` and let it bubble up…?!

Comment: I agree with @deceze. It is not hard to obtain what you want, but it doesn't make too much sense. If there is an error in `function1()` call it won't reach the `print(true)` anyways. It seems like you are catching your exception just to throw it again using `return 'Error'` instead of a proper exception

Comment: @deceze If I just don't catch the exception in my function, which event can I take in my if statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There aren't too many ways about it. The pythonic way to indicate *errors* are exceptions, so that would be:

```
def function1():
    doSomething()
    return A

try:
    function1()
except Exception:
    print('An error occurred')
else:
    print(True)
```

If you don't like exceptions for whatever reason, the only alternative is to ascribe a success or failure meaning to *return values*, for which you'd usually return any *truthy* value on success and any *falsey* value on failure:

```
def function1():
    try:
        doSomething()
        return A
    except:
        return False

if function1():
    print(True)
```

As long as `A` is something—anything—*truthy*, e.g. any object, this will do just fine.

Comment: It's a mess that a function doesn't return a consistent type of result. A or False. I would not suggest that.

Comment: Yeah, me neither, hence why I favored the first way in my answer.

Comment: `return None` is also an option - then it's a valid result or None, it's easy to check and still works in case A has false bool value (e.g. a list that is empty)

Comment: @h4z3 Depends on whether the difference between an empty list and `False`/`None` is or isn’t important to you. That depends on what the definition of the job of that function is. Can’t it fail by definition and “at worst” return a non-value, or does it have a genuine failure state?

Comment: I just mentioned None because or Wariored's comment that "False" is a completely other type. I got to Python from Java and C# where "null" is a valid (although problematic) value for an object. But I can see some valid usages, e.g. when passing the returned value to another function, None is often used to denote that default value should be used. :)

Comment: @h4z3 Yes, that’s very true, `None` should probably be the preferred non-value here. But again, in the end it depends on the “mission statement” of this specific function.

Answer (score 1):

Just return True or False in your function:

```
 def function1():
   try:
     doSomething()
     return True
   except:
     return False

if function1():
    print ("Ok")
else:
    print ("Error")
```

Comment: I can't return a bool into my function, my example variable A is not a bool. I'll precise it into my question.

Comment: You still can return False in the except instead of the 'error' string? Your 'A' will be considered as True in the if statement

Comment: It works, I didn't know that 'A' was considered as True in the if statement in my case...

Answer (score 0):

Just return a tuple instead of a single value, where the first element is an error or None in the case of success:

```
def function1():
  try:
    result = doSomething()
    return None, result
  except:
    return 'Error', None

err, result = function1()
if not err:
  print('ok')
  doNext(result)
else:
  print(err)
```

Answer (score -1):

The if statements in your code executes only when the conditions are True that means when function1 isn't equals to 'Error' but literally the function1 is returning 'Error' that's why it isn't printing True.